# What conditions are necessary for any differential $1$-form to be the differential of a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I've been learning some basic differential geometry on $\R^n$ recently and feel like I have begun to grasp the concept of a $1$-form. To reiterate, let $T_p(\R^n)$ be the tangent space at a point $p\in\R^n$, and $T_p^{*}(\R^n) = (T_p(\R^n))^{\vee}$. Then a differential $1-$form $\omega$ is a map

$$\omega:U\rightarrow \bigcup_{p\,\in\, U}\,T_p^{*}(\R^n)$$

Where in particular,

$$\omega:p\mapsto \omega_p$$

Now a particular *example* of a $1$-form is one induced by a smooth function $f$. We call this the differential of $f$, and its action is essentially

$$(df):p\mapsto (df)_p$$

Where $(df)_p$ acts on a vector $v = \sum_i v_ie_i$ as

$$(df)_p(v) = \sum_{i+1}^n v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)$$

I've noticed that in a lot of theorems I've encountered there's been some sort of one-to-one equivalence between seemingly disparate objects. For example, the set of smooth vector fields $\mathfrak{X}$ defined on some subset $U$ of $\R^n$ has a one-to-one correspondence with the derivations on $C^{\infty}(U)$. This prompts me to ask the question:

1. Is there some well-defined subclass of differential $1$-forms such that each one of its members can be rationalized as the differential of a smooth function?
2. What are the necessary conditions for the above to happen?

Comment: For $f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy$ to be the differential of a function it is necessary that $\partial f/\partial y=\partial g/\partial x$.

Comment: AFAIK there is no more specific condition than this: that suck smooth function exist. There is a theorem that says that under some circumstances this function exists, however these conditions are not necessary.

Comment: A necessary condition is that the exterior derivative of $\omega$ be 0. (i.e that the form is closed). This is true for differential forms of arbitrary degree.

Comment: Alternately, such a function exists iff the integral of $\omega$ around any closed loop is zero. (This applies to arbitrary smooth manifolds, including $\mathbb{R}^n$.)